# Read XLS file from VB6

Tags: excel, vb6, xls

How can I read an XLS file from VB6? I don't want to use ADO or Automation.

- [ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q278973/) isn't going to work for my particular XLS files, because [it guesses](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196) the data types of the columns from the data in the first few rows.
- Automation is out, because Excel may not be installed on the machine.

I'm hoping for recommendations based on experience - [I know how to Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=read+xls+vb6&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US&ie=utf8&oe=utf8&rlz=1I7GGLL_en-GB) :)

Answer (score 1):

**ADO**

For IMEX=1 setting HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows to 0 does miracles. I'm wondering if this can be supplied as a parameter of the connect string.

Answer (score 0):

To make the ADO driver a bit more reliable, you can use add two pieces to your connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\blah.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;MAXSCANROWS=12"
```

That will force the driver to scan 12 rows before making a decision on data types.

Comment: Thanks: I guess 12 rows is a bit better, but I'm hoping for a more general method. XLS files don't have to be in columns at all.